# Moving WPF .NET Core window to second screen

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, screen

I'm trying to create a second window in my WPF .NET Core application.

In WPF with .NET Framework I was able to move a window to the second screen by using the following code:

```
var screens = Screen.AllScreens.Length;
Screen s;
if (screens > 1)
{
    s = Screen.AllScreens[1];
    var r = s.WorkingArea;
    this.Top = r.Top;
    this.Left = r.Left;
}
```

But the Screen class is not accessible in .NET Core. Could someone offer an alternative way of achieving the same result?

Comment: There is no Screen class in .net framework library

Comment: Screen is stil winforms. See the namespace. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?view=netcore-3.1  add the reference to project and using to code.

Comment: Yes but the point is: it doesn't exist in .NET Core.

Comment: When you click on the link. See the version dropdown? Says .net core 3.1 for me

Comment: That's a good point, thank you! I haven't been able to find the .NET Core version of the dll on my computer yet though.